# Problem on keyboard function keys

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard is from [iqunix](https://iqunix.store/). The function keys on my keyboards(e.g. F1, F2) is remapped to media keys, so when I press `F11` my volume is turned up, although I wanted to open up the developer console in my browser. Even if I am pressing `FN+F12` it's still turning up the volume. I have also tried to press `FN + Caps Lock`. It doesn't work for me neither.

Comment: Not sure about your issue with function keys, but if your browser is firefox; CTRL+Shift+C will open the developer console && CTRL+Shift+Z (twice) closes it.